# How to change the ArangoDB Foxx App Generate Location

Tags: arangodb

Is it possible to generate a new foxx app in an arbitrary location?

```
foxx-manager install EMPTY /some-app
```

creates and installs some-app from the default /var/lib/arangodb-apps location. I'm running ArangoDB 2.7.1. I've tried the --javascript.app-path switch, but it isn't recognized as an option even though it's referenced  [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/Develop/Folder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javascript.app-path` switch should work (alternatively you can try using the `app-path` setting in the `javascript` section of your `arangod.conf`) but it will be used for *all* Foxx apps. However this is an option of the `arangod` server (which performs the actual installation of Foxx apps), not of the `foxx-manager` CLI (which just tells the server what to install).

There's no way to install a Foxx app outside the `app-path`. Mount paths are always translated to paths that are relative to the `app-path`.

You're saying the switch isn't recognized. Can you give an example of how you tried to use it and the error message you received? Are you running `arangod` directly? And have you made sure there isn't already a daemonized version of arangod running in the background?